# CakePHP : call controllers functions in external php files

Tags: php, cakephp, redirect, header, cakephp-1.2

This is my situation:

```
1) a simple_php.php file in webroot folder
2) the users_controller.php in the app/controllers
3) the follow function in the users_controller.php :
```

```php
function login_flat($user_id){

    $user_data = $this->User->find('first', array(
                                   'conditions' => array('User.id'=>$user_id)));

    if($this->Auth->login($user_data)){

      $this->Cookie->write('User.id', $this->Auth->user('id'), true, '+2 hour');

      $this->Session->setFlash(__('Welcome back !', true));

      $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'posts', 'action'=>'index'));   
      exit();
    }
    else{
      echo 'ERROR!!';
      exit();
    }
}
```

(a simple function to login user. NOTE : I know it's not safe , but it's for test only)

Now, If I call via browser the function ( eg. `www.mysite.com/users/login_flat/13` ) it WORKS ! but ... I need to call it via an other file, the simple_php.php located in the webroot of my domain.

I try with the php "header" function. It "call" (redirect) to the login_flat function , but the login not work !!! :(

Have any suggestion ? thx in advance.

P.S.
I'm using cakephp 1.2.6

------------- EDIT ------------------

I solve my trouble reading this:--> [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762714/not-logged-in-after-manual-login-in-cakephp-if-redirected-logged-in-if-no-redir)

Comment: Do you really need the simple_php.php script, or do you it just for the redirect? You might also consider rewriting the simple_php page be part of your CakePHP application.

Comment: Does the redirect from simple_page.php to login_flat go to the same URL that you tested in your browser manually? Please show the code you're using to perform the redirect from simple page to login flat

Comment: this is the code I uses for the redirect in the simple_php file :  `code` header("Location: http://www.mysite.com/users/login_flat/".$user_id.""); `code`

Answer (score 0):

From the OP:
this is the code I uses for the redirect in the simple_php file :

```
header("Location:http://".$subdomain_locale.".".$site_subdomain.".com/users/login_via_app/".$user‌​_id."");
```

Which will redirect to

```
/users/login_via_app/13
```

Which is the wrong url, as it *should* be redirecting to

```
/users/login_flat/13
```

Also be sure to put 'exit();' after sending the header and check that nothing else is output before that, otherwise your redirect won't work

And, please check if the $sudomain_locale and $site_subdomain variables contains the right value, or debug the whole URL using this, instead of performing the redirect;

```
echo "this is the URL that will be redirected to:<br>";
print_r("Location:http://".$subdomain_locale.".".$site_subdomain.".com/users/login_via_app/".$user‌​_id."");
exit();
```

Comment: i make a mistake in teh previous comment. this what I do : `header("Location: mysite.com/users/login_flat/".$user_id."");`

Comment: And does it actually *do* the redirect, or is it not redirecting? Otherwise check the URL using the extra information I added to my answer, and check for the 'exit'

Comment: Also, when redirecting, either use a relative path (/users/login_flat) OR include http:// in the URL

Comment: yes it do the redirect, but it do not login the user. If i call via browser the url , it do the login. this is my trouble :S

Comment: Is the content of $user_data the same in both situations? E.g. When redirecting and directly accessing the same URL? Have you tried to enable debugging and checked the output of your SQL statements?

Comment: yes, I tried it just now. I've same value :( Other suggestions?

Comment: however I notice that it go through the if statement and write the Cookie , but after the last redirect `$this->redirect(array('controller'=>'posts', 'action'=>'index'));` the user was not logged in .